# php mysqli script mysteriously not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['Username'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('****','****','****','****');
if($mysqli->errno)
{
    mail("**@yahoo.com", "***/Account.php Connection Error", $mysqli->error . "\nUser: " . $_SESSION['Username']);
}
else 
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Expires, Expires WHERE EMail=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['Username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($FirstName, $LastName, $Expires);
    $stmt->store_result();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
                ....
```

I am getting VERY strange behavior. I am receiving the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/content/42/7401242/html/****/Account.php on line 12`

I use this EXACT code on many other pages and it works perfectly. Any thoughts why I might be getting this error randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if you are binding username with email. and also u are missing `FROM` clause

```
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Expires from Expires WHERE EMail=?");
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['Username']);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^-----------------be sure if its email variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the `FROM` before the table name

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Expires FROM Expires WHERE EMail=?
```